# Inline parsing array with multiple types

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a datasource outside my control that gives me an array with different data types that I need to process before using. The real datasource has more than 2 data types, but they are always in the same, known order.

I currently use an intermediate value (`rawValues`), but would very much like to avoid this.

```
const rawValues = getData(); // e.g. ["12.5", "42", "hello"]

const [num1, num2, text] = [
  Number(rawValues[0]), 
  Number(rawValues[1]), 
  rawValues[2]
];
```

The only inline option I know would be a somewhat messy `.map()` such as:

```
const [num1, num2, text] = getData()
  .map((data, i) => i < 2 ? Number(data) : data);
```

I'd also like to avoid the "magic number 2" and arguable unreadability of this approach.

I thought about just testing weak equality of each array member for coerce-ability `(Number(data) == data)` in a map like

```
const [num1, num2, text] = getData()
  .map((data, i) => Number(data) == data ? Number(data) : data);
```

This has the added benefit of making the conversion more flexible, but risks problems if the incoming number isn't exactly representable by the JavaScript standard number type.

Just to reiterate my question -- what is the best (or most idiomatic) way to deal with this incoming data, preferably without creating any temp variables? This isn't about code golfing (I'm not worried about # lines of code), but about readable code that avoids polluting scope with a temp value.

Comment: Why is the order fixed?

Comment: You can use [ES6 destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) of an array.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee by fixed I mean that the `getData()` function always returns an array with the various data types in the same order. That is, you don't have to sniff the data to figure it out. Kind of like rows of an arbitrary spreadsheet that has strings, digits, dates, etc. But not helpfully labelled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd represent the known types as an array of types (which are constructors which can be called):

```
const types = [Number, Number, String];
```

then process the incoming data as

```
const [num1, num2, text] = getData().map((x, i) => types[i](x));
```

The above is designed to meet your desire not to have any intermediate variables, but I don't really see the point in worrying about that. They are essentially free, or even beneficial in some cases from a self-documenting code perspective.

Comment: Thanks. Of the answers so far this seems like the most readable and flexible. It still has an intermediate value, but it's not one that's just an almost-copy of the data. I would have never thought about doing it this way and am happy to learn a new approach!

Comment: Could also use `.shift()` on the types array and eliminate need for the index: `const cooked = raw.map(x => types.shift()(x));`

Comment: @BenFletcher I would avoid the shift, since it destroys the array. I've modified the answer to use no intermediate variables.

Comment: Yes, in my final implementation I used the types array as the arguments passed into an IIFE and then shift[ed] them off one-by-one. I also didn't like leaving behind a destroyed array, so the IIFE leaves behind nothing but the list of types is still very readable.

Comment: @BenFletcher I don't understand. Even if you pass the array into another function, IIFE or otherwise, unless you copy shifting from it will destroy it.

Comment: `const [num1, num2, string] = (types => 
  getData().map(e => 
    types.shift()(e)))(Number, Number, String);`. So, yes, the array is consumed but not in a way that pollutes the scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const [num1, num2, text] = getData().map(n => !n || isNaN(+n) ? n : +n);
```

Or:

```
let [num1, num2, text] = getData();
num1 = +num1;
 num2 = +num2;
```

Comment: `+n || n);` what does this part do?

Comment: @kunal parse to a number if possible, otherwise take the string

Comment: How about when `n` is `"0"` ?

Comment: Why can't we use the Number constructor?

Comment: Now it will fail on empty strings. Try `isNaN("")` or `isNaN(+"")`

Comment: @titus finally got it :)

Answer (score 1):

> they are always in the same, known order

You could  unpack the array from `getData` into properties of a result object.

```js
let getData = function(){ return ["12.5", "42", "hello"]; }

let result = {};
[result["float"],result["int"],result["string"]] = getData();

console.log(result);
```

I was unsure what you would want the property names to be. They could just be num1, num2, string as well. The naming is kind of besides the point though I think.

Comment: Thanks. This is also a good approach I hadn't considered. It doesn't coerce the values to the proper types, but that wouldn't be a difficult step to add.

Comment: @BenFletcher - I was under the impression the types were known, if that is the case, you could always map the types on the right hand side of the expression as is seen in some of the other answers here.